# A way to convert a binary tree into a grid

Tags: trees, lattices

Wondering if there is a way to convert a binary tree into a grid such as this:

```
                    a
                  /   \
                 b     c
                / \   / \
               d   e f   g


                    or


                 d--b--e
                    |
                    a
                    |
                 f--c--g


                    to


                 d--b--e
                 |  |  |
                 y--a--x
                 |  |  |
                 f--c--g
```

An arbitrary sized binary tree. I'm not super familiar with binary tree properties so I am not sure if this would even be possible or if edge cases would prevent it from being possible.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "convert a binary tree into a grid"? In particular, do you want each edge in the binary tree to correspond to an edge of the grid?

Comment: I am not sure exactly, it starts to get confusing right then lol! It seems you'd have to test out large binary trees to get a sense for their shape, and then see what kinds of grids they can fit into and the patterns of connectivity. But that seems brittle, so I'm wondering if there is a more robust approach.

Comment: If you don't have a question, what kind of answer do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vertex in the grid has $O(d)$ vertices at distance $d$ from it. In contrast, the complete binary tree of height $h$ as $2^h$ vertices at distance $h$ from the root. Therefore there is no isometric embedding of arbitrary binary trees in the grid. Similar considerations show that there is also no embedding of bounded distortion (in which distances increase by at most a constant factor).